# How to connect OPC UA node red client to local server?

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud, node-red, opc, opc-ua

I have an OPC UA Server in my local network to which I want to establish a connection via the OPC UA client node provided by node red. The node red client runs in the IBM Bluemix Cloud. I tried following configuration for the client node. Is my endpoint configuration right? Am I missing a configuration for my network?

Configuration:

> Endpoint: opc.tcp://[ServerIP]:4840/UA/NameServer

I get an error when connecting:

> OPC READ OPC UA connection error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Comment: What error? Also does the server have a public IP address or is it behind a NAT router?

Comment: Error: "OPC READ OPC UA connection error: connect ECONNREFUSED 
I think its behind a NAT Server. Should not be a public IP.

Comment: Please edit the question to add the answers to my questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are trying to configure Node-RED running on a Bluemix machine (on the internet) to connect to a private IP address on your network behind a NAT router.

This won't work unless you use your public IP address and probably set up something like port forwarding

Answer (score 0):

> Endpoint: opc.tcp://[ServerIP]:4840/UA/NameServer

This is not an Endpoint, this is the Server URL. The Endpoints are a list of different types of connection and services that the Server supports, including different types of security and encryption. This list is returned by the server when an Endpoint Discovery request is made, then the client should choose one of the endpoints and try to open a Session.

> OPC READ OPC UA connection error: connect ECONNREFUSED

If this message is really returned from the server that means the Server is already accessible from your client, but may you are trying to connect with the wrong service / login (if any) / security or the Server is refusing your client certificate.